# Resource allocation with Apache Spark and Mesos

Tags: apache-spark, mesos

So I've deployed a cluster with Apache Mesos and Apache Spark and I've several jobs that I need to execute on the cluster. I would like to be sure that a job has enough resources to be successfully executed, and if it is not the case, it must return an error.

Spark provides several settings like `spark.cores.max` and `spark.executor.memory` in order to limit the resources used by the job, but there is no settings for the lower bound (e.g. set the minimal number of core to 8 for the job).

I'm looking for a way to be sure that a job has enough resources before it is executed (during the resource allocation for instance), do you know if it is possible to get this information with Apache Spark on Mesos?

Comment: You'll need to test and benchmark. You can't know before hand how much resources you need. You can estimate at least based on your input data how much memory will actually need per say. And you can also use the Spark UI to check for eventual data created or shuffled or transformed knowing there size. Etc

Comment: I agree with you. My problem is that I know exactly how it takes to execute one job (e.g. 4cores & 200m), but when I'm doing a spark-submit  I am not sure Mesos will allocate enough resources before the execution of the job. Some times the job fails and the error message `Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources` is displayed. Spark can configure the upper bound for the job, but not the lower bound..

Comment: That's not what the issue means. That seems like the master who didn't want to register the job for lack of resources. Maybe some other job is still executing or you have a miss configuration on the mesos cluster size. I have very basic knowledge about mesos, so I can't help you with that area.

Comment: For instance, Mesos have the following available resources: 1 CPU and 200m of memory, and my job needs 2CPU and 150m. The job will be executed successfully because I set `spark.cores.max` at 2, but spark doesn't care...
If I execute spark-submit with 300m of memory, spark is executed even if there are not enough memory, but it enters in an infinite loop `Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources`.
I am actually looking for a way to detect these 2 cases before the execution of the spark-submit.

Comment: @eliasah No problem, as you said there are some other process still executed on Mesos. I just want to detect that it is impossible to start this spark job.

Comment: That's the reason of the infinite loop. But you can set that in the SparkConf. (Something like submit max retry property) I'm on my phone. I have very limited internet access to search for the exact property. You can also tweak the submit script to return a error if the application fails.

Comment: Concerning the infinite loop, I've already located the related source code (`spark/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/TaskSchedulerImpl.scala`), but it is only possible to modify the STARVATION_TIMEOUT_MS parameter. Of course I can modify spark to fit my needs, but it is not really maintainable in the time.